# ScalaTest - writing custom matchers

Tags: scala, testing, matcher, scalatest

I am running into a problem while writing a custom matcher for NodeSeq:

```
private def matchXML(expected: NodeSeq) = new Matcher[NodeSeq] {
  def apply(left: NodeSeq): MatchResult = MatchResult(left xml_== expected,
    "XML structure was not the same (watch spaces in tag texts)",
    "XML messages were equal")
}
```

This compiles, but the following piece of code:

```
val expected : NodeSeq = ...
val xml : NodeSeq = ... 
xml should matchXML(expected)
```

causes:

```
error: overloaded method value should with alternatives:
(beWord: XMLStripDecoratorTests.this.BeWord)XMLStripDecoratorTests.this.ResultOfBeWordForAnyRef[scala.collection.GenSeq[scala.xml.Node]] <and>
(notWord: XMLStripDecoratorTests.this.NotWord)XMLStripDecoratorTests.this.ResultOfNotWordForAnyRef[scala.collection.GenSeq[scala.xml.Node]] <and>
(haveWord: XMLStripDecoratorTests.this.HaveWord)XMLStripDecoratorTests.this.ResultOfHaveWordForSeq[scala.xml.Node] <and>
(rightMatcher: org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher[scala.collection.GenSeq[scala.xml.Node]])Unit
cannot be applied to (org.scalatest.matchers.Matcher[scala.xml.NodeSeq])
xml should (matchXML(expected))
```

Any ideas what this means?

Comment: What is the definition of NodeSeq ?

Comment: @MikaëlMayer I'd suppose `scala.xml.NodeSeq`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Why this fails to typecheck:**

The type checker works in the following way.

```
xml.should(matchXML(expected))
```

- Because the method `should` is not part of a `NodeSeq`, the compiler tries to find an [implicit conversion](http://doc.scalatest.org/1.0/org/scalatest/matchers/ShouldMatchers.html) for `xml` to a `ShouldMatcher`.
  The book "Programming in Scala" specifies that such implicit conversion should be the most specific:

> "Up through Scala 2.7, that was the end of the story. Whenever
>   multiple implicit conversions applied, the compiler refused to choose
>   between them. ... Scala 2.8 loosens this rule. If one of the available
>   conversions is strictly more speciﬁc than the others, then the
>   compiler will choose the more speciﬁc one. ... one implicit conversion
>   is more speciﬁc than another if one of the following applies: The
>   argument type of the former is a subtype of the latter’s. .."

- Because `NodeSeq` extends `Seq[Node]`, the following function

  `convertToSeqShouldWrapper[T](o : scala.GenSeq[T]) : SeqShouldWrapper[T]`

  is therefore the most specific one among all others.

The program is rewritten as:

```
`convertToSeqShouldWrapper(xml).should(matchXML(expected))`
```

where `convertToSeqShouldWrapper(xml)` is a `SeqShouldWrapper[T]` where `T = GenSeq[Node]`.

The method `should` from `SeqShouldWrapper` accepts a `Matcher[T]` which is a function of type `T => MatchResult`. Therefore, it accepts a `Matcher[GenSeq[Node]]`.

Because `T` is appearing to the left of the arrow, matchers are not [covariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29) in `T`, but contravariant. A `NodeSeq` is a `GenSeq[Node]`, so a `Matcher[GenSeq[Node]]` is a `Matcher[NodeSeq]`, not the opposite.This explains the above error, where the method `should` cannot accept a `Matcher[NodeSeq]` and requires a `Matcher[GenSeq[Node]]`.

**2 Solutions**

- Replace All instances of `NodeSeq` to `GenSeq[Node]` so that the type matches everywhere.
- Alternatively, wrap xml explicitely with the conversion function.

  `convertToAnyShouldWrapper(xml).should(matchXML(expected))`

Comment: While the second solution works, the first one (converting everything to `Seq[Node]`) still shows the same error.

Comment: I was able to solve this by converting everything to `GenSeq[Node]`. I am using `scalatest 2.0 M5`, hence the difference perhaps.

Comment: Indeed, with this version, the signature of the convertToSeqShouldWrapper method is `GenSeq[T] => SeqShouldWrapper[T]`. So I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This looks to me like your `matchXML` method is not in scope.